# How do i form the inequality $ -5\le 3\cos x - 4\sin x\le5$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

We know that

$-1\le \cos x\le1$ so we if we multiply 3 so we get $-3\le 3\cos x\le 3$ and we also know that $-1\le \sin x\le 1$ and and again we multiply 4 we get $-4\le 4\sin x\le 4$ and we can add these two inequality we get $-7\le 3\cos x - 4\sin x\le 7$ but how in the above inequality is forming i m not able to understand at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}3\cos x-4\sin x&=5\left(\frac35\cos x-\frac45\sin x\right)\\&=5\left(\cos\alpha\cos x-\sin\alpha\sin x\right),\end{align}where $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ is such that $\cos\alpha=\frac35$ and that $\sin\alpha=\frac45$. Therefore$$3\cos x-4\sin x=5\cos(\alpha+x)\in[-5,5].$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint :
\begin{eqnarray*}
3 \cos \theta -4 \sin \theta = R \cos ( \theta +\phi) .
\end{eqnarray*}
$R=?$

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake **adding** the two inequalities when $3 cos(x)- 4 sin(x)$ requires that you **subtract** the two.

Comment: "a-  b" is not "a+ b"!  You can't "add directly" because the problem say "subtract"!